# Do axios request n times,where n is the length of previous response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

Using axios, I would like to convert addresses to their respective coordinates.

1. Get list of addresses from an API.
2. Take the object RESPONSE from number 1 and convert each address of the RESPONSE to
   coordinate using Google API
3. Then I would like to add those coordinate key to each object RESPONSE.

Here's my attempt but it won't work since it's asynchronous.

```
 let array = [];
    axios.get('https://www.data.qld.gov.au/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=346d58fc-b7c1- 
    4c38-bf4d-c9d5fb43ce7b')
        .then((response) => {
            const records = response.data.result.records;
            records.forEach((record) => {
                axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
                   params: {
                     address: record.address,
                     key: GOOGLE_KEY,
                  }
               }).then(response => {
                  record.response.coordinate;
                  array.push(record);

               });

        });
```

I was thinking, is it possible to do the then((response)) n times based on the length of RESPONSE object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to achieve the desired outcome.

```
(async () => {
    const {
        data: {
            result: { records }
        }
    } = await axios.get(
        "https://www.data.qld.gov.au/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=346d58fc-b7c1-4c38-bf4d-c9d5fb43ce7b"
    );

    const coordinates = await Promise.all(
        records.map(async (record) => {
            const response = await axios.get(
                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",
                {
                    params: {
                        address: record.address,
                        key: GOOGLE_KEY
                    }
                }
            );

            return response.coordinate;
        })
    );
})();
```